# Name of a plot with continuous y versus categorical x

Tags: data-visualization, terminology

What is the formal name of a plot that has a continuous variable on the y axis and a categorical variable on the x axis where dots are used to indicate the (x,y) values. Kind of like a barplot with dots instead of bars. For example, a plot with the ID's of 100 different individuals on the x axis and their weights on the y axis.

Tom

Comment: Do you mean to only ask about cases where there's one observation per x-value (as in your example) or not? If you're asking more generally, how are overlapping points dealt with? (It changes what I'd call the plot)

Comment: Yes, one observation per x value.

Comment: Sounds a bit like what's sometimes called an index plot -- value against observation order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dot plot" is the most common name when there is one value per category. The term is defined as such by [William Cleveland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_S._Cleveland) in his book, *The Elements of Graphing Data*. Here's a image from the book.

[image]

Other references: Jon Peltier on [dot plots in Excel](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/DotPlot.html) and Naomi Robbins/Stephen Few on [Dot plots vs bar charts](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/b-eye/dot_plots.pdf).

For the case where there are multiple continuous values per category, dot plot is still used but it's also common to see stripchart or (one-dimensional) scatter plot.

Answer (score 1):

There is no formal name, but a frequently used name is "strip chart", after the R function `stripchart`. They might also be called "dot plots", but this term is also used for [the variation where there's a count variable on the *y*-axis and each case gets a dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_plot_(statistics)).

Comment: It's formal name is  "scatter plot" I guess and R call it stripchart

Comment: @MFR Usually we reserve the term "scatterplot" for the case where both variables are continuous.